# Nudge users to fix their closed questions themselves before calling others to reopen it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, help-center

The help page on [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions) lists all kinds of ways to have your question reopened, but most of them aren't really effective:

- > Leave a comment to that effect on the question itself.

  Well, that usually doesn't help get your question more attention. You can only reach one user through the comment, and after a question is closed, it's unlikely it'll be reopened just by having the OP post "Please reopen this!".
- > Flag the question for moderator attention.

  We don't really want moderators to deal with these kinds of flags, do we? The community can handle reopening on its own.
- > If you have at least 3,000 reputation points, vote to reopen yourself.

  That's a valid point, but it's almost too obvious to people with VTC privileges.

The only tip that makes sense here is

> Be sure that you've read the close notice and any comments on the question

… because the close reasons mention that you need to edit your question to fix it.

Still, that information should definitely come first in the help pages. **The ultimate priority for a user should be to fix their post**, which automatically puts it in the reopen review queue. Then, and *only then*, if the question isn't reopened, should they appeal to others personally (e.g. by flagging).

Please update the Help pages to mention that crucial aspect.

Comment: Just to note. You don't need 3,000 reputation to vote to close or re-open your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi True. This also isn't mentioned in the Help Center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though most people are far more likely to encounter the close notices (which DO emphasize editing over anything else) than this help center page, I've updated that page for all sites.

The first paragraph now reads:

> Stack Exchange is collaboratively built, maintained, and moderated by the community. If you see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its closure, you should first **try to edit the question to improve it as much as possible. Read the close notice and any comments carefully to address concerns raised there. Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening.**

(Bold part is new.)